# java.security.ProviderException error

Tags: java, exception, objectoutputstream

I have recently been trying to make the following piece of code work:

```
...

// Create an ObjectOutputStream to write the game out.
ObjectOutputStream stream = null;
try{ stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)); }
catch(IOException ioe){}

// Write this game out.
try { stream.writeObject(this); } catch (IOException ioe) {}
```

The problem is that I continue to get an exception on the last line:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.security.ProviderException: Error parsing configuration
```

Does someone know how to fix this? I'd greatly appreciate it if you told me.

(By the way, all elements that I'm trying to write out are Serializable)

The full StackTrace is the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.security.ProviderException: Error parsing configuration
at sun.security.pkcs11.Config.getConfig(Config.java:71)
at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:110)
at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$4.run(ProviderConfig.java:262)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:244)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:224)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:215)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(ProviderList.java:313)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:140)
at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:659)
at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:129)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$100(ObjectStreamClass.java:51)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:204)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:201)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.writeNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:675)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDescriptor(ObjectOutputStream.java:649)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1263)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1212)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1275)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1212)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1408)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:329)
at chess.ChessGame.saveGame(ChessGame.java:256)
at chess.ChessGame.access$2(ChessGame.java:239)
at chess.ChessGame$3.actionPerformed(ChessGame.java:133)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:389)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:809)
at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuItemUI.doClick(AquaMenuItemUI.java:137)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:850)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.ConfigurationException: Unknown keyword '⌊⌠䍯湦楧畲慴楯渠晩汥⁴漠慬汯眠瑨攠卵湐䭃匱ㄠ灲潶楤敲⁴漠畴楬楺攊⌠瑨攠卭慲瑃慲摓敲癩捥猠慮搠潵爠捲祰瑯杲慰桩挠晲慭敷潲欬⁩映楴⁩猠慶慩污扬攊⌊੮慭攠㴠䑡牷楮ਊ摥獣物灴楯渠㴠卵湐䭃匱ㄠ慣捥獳楮朠䵡挠体⁘⁓浡牴䍡牤卥牶楣敳ਊ汩扲慲礠㴠⽵獲⽬楢數散⽓浡牴䍡牤卥牶楣敳⽰正猱ㄯ瑯步湤偋䍓ㄱ⹳漊੨慮摬敓瑡牴異䕲牯牳‽⁩杮潲敁汬ਊ慴瑲楢畴敳‽⁣潭灡瑩扩汩瑹�', line 1
    at sun.security.pkcs11.Config.parse(Config.java:425)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.Config.<init>(Config.java:194)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.Config.getConfig(Config.java:67)
    ... 75 more
```

Comment: please give the full StackTrace

Comment: You are serializing `this` in your code. The error is related to Java security providers, perhaps to SSL certificates. Is there anything in your class that relates to `java.security` ?

Comment: There is nothing that has to do with java.security in my code. I'll give the full StackTrace though.

Comment: what code is at line 71

Comment: That is the sun.security.pkcs11.Config class, which I don't have the source code for (the Java developers made it). What I do have the code for is ChessGame's saveGame() method (the chunk of code I displayed comes from there.)

Comment: It is actually a runtime error [read this](http://www.terryanderson.ca/debugging/run.html) i hope you can solve it yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! Unfortunately, the problem isn't in debugging; it's in actually understanding what the exception is and why it was thrown.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? If you're on Windows and if it's Java 6, try Java 7. Although I don't understand why it would pop up in your environment (perhaps you have installed some extra tools in Java), your problem appears similar to http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6581254 ; similar enough to try Java 7 if you are using Java 6.

Comment: I'm not on Windows, and I do have Java 7, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using Eclipse, and the permissions of the path I was trying to save to were 752.